Attached volume not available to docker services
I successfully attached a volume to my ubuntu host as can be seen below.
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.2G  2.1M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        99G   37G   58G  39% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb        100G  2.0G   98G   2% /data
tmpfs           3.2G   28K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1001


However /dev/sdb is not available to the applications running on that host. The error raised is  could not extend file "base/16384/17093": No space left on device\nHINT:  Check free disk space.

Were those applications told to use /data, or are they still using the root volume?

@grawity my assumption was that the applications would use the available storage under /data once the storage under root / location becomes depleted


my assumption was that the applications would use the available storage under /data once the storage under root / location becomes depleted

It doesn't work that way. That's why it's /data and not just a second /.
This is the same basic model as on Windows, where a new disk would be mounted on a new drive letter (such as E:) and only programs that were explicitly told to put files there, will put files there – programs that proactively look for new disks tend to be the rare exception, not the rule (and I'd imagine not well-liked exceptions at that).
So you will need to configure each program to store its data on the new volume, moving existing folders as needed.
Having a single / filesystem span several disks and automatically share their space is technically possible, but not with your setup – it would require the server to use either a specific filesystem that knows how to deal with multiple disks (Btrfs or ZFS) or the use of a "volume manager" that makes both disks appear as one to the filesystem (such as LVM2 or mdadm). I'm assuming your VM doesn't use Btrfs, and the lsblk output says that it definitely doesn't use LVM2 or such.
(I guess you could start using one of those methods from the second disk onwards... but it isn't all that useful with VMs where it's much easier to just extend the size of the existing volume.)
